# How to quit / terminate / stop a j2me midlet?

Tags: java, java-me, runtime, midlet, midp

Surprisingly terminating a midlet doesn't work in my application. Maybe it is because I'm using Threads, but `destroyApp()` and `notifyDestroyed()` are not sufficient.

Take for example the following code:

```
protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    System.out.println("destroying");
    notifyDestroyed();
}
protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
   try {
        // init modules
        controller.initialize();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        viewer.showAlert("error in startApp() init controller");
        destroyApp(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: I didn't find a solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485943/question-for-terminate-app-in-j2me-but-it-doesnt-mean-quit-from-application unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifically calling `notifyDestroyed()` from inside `startApp()`.

My best guess is that the handset (or emulator) you are trying this on doesn't handle it too well.

Try this instead:

- When `controller.initialize()` throws an exception, display a simple `Form` with a single "Exit" `Command` and a `StringItem` error message.
- Call `notifyDestroyed()` from a `CommandListener.commandAction()` callback.

As far as threads are concerned, it is up to you to have them nicely terminate when the user wants to exit your application.

Most MIDP runtimes will be able to deal with some threads not terminating nicely but leaving system resources not properly cleaned may cause problems, especially on platforms that try to never terminate the Java Virtual Machine process itself.

Answer (score 0):

you should call 'notifyDestroyed' method to exit your application not 'destroyApp' method.